# Jackson ObjectMapper polymorphic deserialization

Tags: java, json, jackson

I cannot seem to figure out how to deserialize my Java object, I have the following:

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public PhoneNumber phone;
}

class PhoneNumber {
    public int areaCode;
    public int local;
}
```

And what I am trying to achieve is:

```
{ 
"name" : null,
 "age" : null,
 "phone" : {
     "areaCode" : null,
     "local" : null
  }
}
```

Code I am trying to achieve this with:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
PolymorphicTypeValidator ptv = BasicPolymorphicTypeValidator.builder().build();
objectMapper.activateDefaultTyping(ptv);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

Person person = new Person()
String value = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(person);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your result or what kind of error you have faced?

Comment: The result I am getting is {"name":null,"age":0,"phone":null}

Comment: Using "PolimorphicTypeValidator" seems off to me. Literally just create an ObjectMapper and cal writeValueAsString. Not further config needed.

Comment: How do your objects look like? Have you created new Person and PhoneNumber objects with your data? I think that your serialization works fine. You forgot to assign data.  `person.setName("..."); person.setPhone(new Phone(.....)); etc.`

Comment: No, I haven't created any additional objects or added any data into them. My end goal is to have a empty skeleton of the Person object (with it the Phone object's fields also included in the json). Is this even achievable?

Comment: Phone object value is null here which is deserialized correctly, other are properties of person, hence appearing, it`s unclear what you want, you should add the ouput json you want to your question.

Comment: The output json which I wish to achieve I have added to the question, it is: { 
"name" : null,
 "age" : null,
 "phone" : {
     "areaCode" : null,
     "local" : null
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Integer instead of int, and you need to initialize the phone number.

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    public Integer age;
    public PhoneNumber phone = new PhoneNumber();
}

class PhoneNumber {
    public Integer areaCode;
    public Integer local;
}
```

Object mapper will generate the expected JSON.

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Person());
```